# How to rename column inside the function?

Tags: r, function, loops, dplyr, tidyverse

How to rename column inside the manually created function using variable name as an argument?

for instance my data is:

```
df <- data.frame (model = c("A","A","A","B","B","B"),
                  category  = c("z3","f4","c5","d3","g6","B6"),
                  sale = c(1001,1050,-300,-150,-25,960))
```

Now I want to rename 'model' column inside the function and I specify column name as an argument

```
chng <- function(x,var1){
  
  x %>% 
  rename(
    var1 = newname)
}

df2 <- chng(df,"model")
```

However this does not work

Comment: What is newname in the function.  should model be named literally as 'newname'?

Comment: yes, just any name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option:

```
chng <- function(x,var1){
  
  names(x)[match(var1, names(x))] <- 'newname'
  return(x)
}

df2 <- chng(df,"model")
df2
```

Output:

```
  newname category sale
1       A       z3 1001
2       A       f4 1050
3       A       c5 -300
4       B       d3 -150
5       B       g6  -25
6       B       B6  960
```

#### For multiple columns

You can use the following code:

```
chng <- function(x,var1,var2){
  
  names(x)[match(c(var1, var2), names(x))] <- c('newname1', "newname2")
  return(x)
}
chng(df, "model", "category")
```

Output:

```
  newname1 newname2 sale
1        A       z3 1001
2        A       f4 1050
3        A       c5 -300
4        B       d3 -150
5        B       g6  -25
6        B       B6  960
```

Comment: is there way to rename several variables within one line? Like: names(x)[match(c(var1,var2), names(x))] <- c('newname1','newname2')

Comment: @Georgecarrick, Yes for sure! Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

We may need to reverse it

```
chng <- function(x,var1){
  
  x %>% 
  rename(
    newname = all_of(var1))
}
```

-testing

```
chng(df, "model")
newname category sale
1       A       z3 1001
2       A       f4 1050
3       A       c5 -300
4       B       d3 -150
5       B       g6  -25
6       B       B6  960
```